# Saving multiple field array in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

//Here is model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

// Task schema
var taskSchema = mongoose.Schema({

 tasktype  : {type: String},
 createdon : {type: Date, default: Date.now},
 createdby : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'User'},
 visitedby : [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'User'}],
 taskinfo  : [{ isactive:Boolean, taskobject:String, taskdetails:String, iscompleted:Boolean}]  

});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Task', taskSchema);
```

// route

```
var Task     = require ('../models/task');
var User       = require ('../models/user');
var config     = require ('../../config');
module.exports = function(app, express) {

    var api = express.Router();

  api.post('/tasks', function (req, res) {
    var task = new Task({
 // ...
 tasktype  : req.body.tasktype,
 taskinfo  : req.body.taskinfo,
      }); 

     task.save(function(err){
        if(err){
           res.send(err);
        return;
        }
       res.json({message:'Task has been created'})
      });
return api
}
```

While all other fields getting saved but the one with array with multiple fields always return blank like  "taskinfo : [ ] "

The post method is REST API to post a task into mongoose database, for array with single field everything working fine but array with multiple field is not getting saved, someone please help me here.

Basic help will be fine, just please teach me how to save "multiple field array".

```
Mongoose doesnot always require subdocument structure and this can be achieved by the above model, please dont advice to use subdocument structure, I want to learn this.
```

Thank You.

Comment: It looks like you have lost some code near line 9 on `route`. Please check.

Comment: I am asking logic for saving array as I dont know how to save array with multiple fields, createdon is saved by default and i am not concerned about other fields right now.

Comment: Does `markModified` works?

Comment: i.e. `doc.markModified("taskinfo")`

Comment: I am very much new to it, what i learn from all the lecture over net from udemy or pluralsight is for each field type fieldname : res.body.fieldname..
Can you tell me complete logic for multiple field array ?

Comment: let me try it just one min pls

Comment: try to add a `doc.markModified("taskinfo")` before saving. Will that work?

Comment: Connected to the database
POST /api/tasks 500 57.358 ms - 1560
ReferenceError: doc is not defined
    at C:\projects\rt\app\routes\api.js:17:1
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\projects\rt\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\projects\rt\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\projects\rt\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request]  and so on

Comment: `doc` means `task`. Please do `task.markModified("taskinfo")`.

Comment: nope its not working,Still producing same result taskinfo empty array, can you tell me basic how to store multiple field array (not subdocument structure) ?

Comment: [
  {
    "_id": "55f4e4f5fe8b36980a611519",
    "tasktype": "Basic",
    "__v": 0,
    "taskinfo": [],
    "visitedby": [],
    "createdon": "2015-09-13T02:52:37.512Z"
  }
]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think if taskinfo has a multiple values and you want to save it as embedded document inside task document. You should have different document of task info. So,you can save like that

```
var TaskInfoSchema = require("taskInfo.js").TaskInfoSchema

var taskSchema = mongoose.Schema({

 tasktype  : {type: String},
 createdon : {type: Date, default: Date.now},
 createdby : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'User'},
 visitedby : [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'User'}],
 taskinfo  : [TaskInfoSchema]  

});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Task', taskSchema);
```

And now you will have different document as task info like

```
var taskInfo = mongoose.Schema({

     isactive:{type:Boolean}, 
     taskobject:{type:String}, 
     taskdetails:{type:String}, 
     iscompleted:{type:Boolean}

    });
    var TaskInfo = mongoose.model('TaskInfo', taskSchema);
    module.exports.TaskInfo = TaskInfo
    module.exports.TaskInfoSchema = taskSchema
```

When you will save task document,

```
 Var TaskInfo = new TaskInfo({
          isactive:true, 
          taskobject:"", 
          taskdetails:"", 
          iscompleted:true
    })



var task = {};
task.tasktype = req.body.tasktype;
```

you can push it

```
 task.taskinfo = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < req.body.taskInfo.length; i++) {
            var taskInfo = new TaskInfo(req.body.taskInfo[i]);
            task.taskinfo.push(taskInfo);
        }
```

Then you will save task document

```
var taskObj = new Task(task);

    taskObj.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
            return;
        }
        res.json({
            message: 'Task has been created'
        })

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for a good description sir, but i have read somewhere that embedded document is not required, can you tell me how to achieve this by creating single schema, also can you suggest me some book or course from where i can learn about inserting array field in mongodb using mongoose. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15208711/mongoose-subdocuments-vs-nested-schema

Comment: Here is how i want my json document: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=118a16030d6d3394f6dab4fdcd31b6fe

Comment: please follow this link before design your schema http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1

Comment: I have tried your ans, but error popsup, someone said i have to use  push to enter & save array.

Comment: also Var TaskInfo = new TaskInfo({
          isactive:true, 
          taskobject:"", 
          taskdetails:"", 
          iscompleted:true
    })
here why we arenot taking input from user ?

Comment: yes you can take it,i declared fields empty as i don't know what will be you get from user..and please taskinfo file require in task domain..i have updated answer..please let me know..what is the status ?

Comment: Sir, I am still facing multiple errors, cannot find module taskinfo.js

Comment: can you help me via teamviewer still same error pop, i have given right path

Comment: Sorry,i could not help you via teamviewer. but if you can push your code on public repo or you can send me your code on email... prabhkahlon429@gmail.com,i can help...

Comment: i am sending mail, just give me a moment please

Comment: I have sent you a mail please check, there is no frontend code as i am using postman client to check  post and get api's

Comment: Thanks for helping me at this level, i will wait for your reply.