# Mongoose nested schema vs nested models

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

What is the difference between nesting schema in schema (subdocuments) vs creating two separate models and referring to them, What about their performance?

**subdocuments:**

```
const postSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  content: String
});

const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  posts: [postSchema]
});

module.export = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

**nested models (Populating by reference):**

```
const postSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  content: String,
  author: { type: String, ref: 'User' }
});
module.export = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);

const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  posts: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post'}]
});
module.export = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

**Edit:** This is not a duplicate question.

In this question: [Mongoose subdocuments vs nested schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15208711/mongoose-subdocuments-vs-nested-schema) - mongoose subdocuments and nested schema is exactly the same.
BUT nested models creating a separate collection in database. 
My question is what is diffrence in nested schema vs nested models, not subdocuments vs nested schema.

Comment: That dupe q/a doesn't directly address seperate models, just embedded schema. This must have been asked already though...

Comment: You could improve the question by using the Mongoose terminology, i.e. "Populating by reference"

Answer (score 15):

When using subdocuments, you actually have a copy of the data within your parent-document, wich allows you to get all the document + sub-document-data in a single query.

When using "nested models" you're not really nesting them, but referencing from the parent-model to the child-model. In this case you have to use [population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), which means you can't get all the data in a single query.

**In short**: subdocuments actually nest the data, and your "nested models" only reference them via their id