# Can one field have many value?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

For example, I have a Scheme like this:

```
var User_schema = new Schema({
  name: string,
  image:{
   avartar_image: String,
   thumbnai_image: String,
   story_image: String
  }
});
```

Is it possible to create one field have many value like that in nodejs and mongoose? And one more, how can I store the image into mongodb and can push back to client using mongoose?, I store image on mongodb with Buffer, like this :

```
var Imgschema = new Schema({
    img: Buffer;
});
```

And if send it to the user when user request a link on server, I do like this:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
        Imgschema.findById('5cdnjwjadhad_ad14', function (err, object) {
          res.contentType('image/png');
          res.send(object.image, {imageToClient: object.image});
        });
      });
```

It will send the image to the user with full screen, but I want the image display inside the  tag with view engine, something like this:

```
<img src="{{imageToClient}}">
```

Any one help please, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Of course you can. There are two ways to store a nested object with mongoose. You can use a [subdocument](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#what-is-a-subdocument-), or just nest the object like you did. The difference between two methods is only a middleware and autogenerated _id field. Here is a good answer: [Mongoose subdocuments vs nested schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15208711/mongoose-subdocuments-vs-nested-schema)
2. Storing images as a buffer in a document is not a good idea, but if you want, you can use base64 decoding to show image in browser.

```html
<img src="{{ 'data:image/png;base64,' + imageBuffer.toString('base64') }}" />
```